# XmlElement InnerText property

Tags: c#, xml, ui-automation

I'm delving into the world of XmlDocument building and thought I'd try to re-build (at least, in part) the Desktop tree given by Microsoft's program UISpy.

So far I am able to grab a child of the desktop and write that to a XML document, and then grab each child of that and write those to an XML document.

So far the code looks like this...

```
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Xml;

namespace MyTestApplication
{
    internal class TestXmlStuff
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
            AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.RootElement;
            TreeWalker treeWalker = TreeWalker.ContentViewWalker;

            XmlNode rootXmlElement = xDocument.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateElement("Desktop"));
            AutomationElement autoElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "GitHub"));
            string name = autoElement.Current.Name;

            while (autoElement != null)
            {
                string lct = autoElement.Current.LocalizedControlType.Replace(" ", "");
                lct = (lct.Equals("") ? "Cusotm" : lct);
                XmlElement temp = (XmlElement)rootXmlElement.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateElement(lct));
                //temp.InnerText = lct;
                string outerXML = temp.OuterXml;
                rootXmlElement = temp;
                autoElement = treeWalker.GetNextSibling(autoElement);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

...and the resulting XML file...

[image: Test XML File]

Now, when I add a line to change the InnerText Property of each XML element, like `temp.InnerText = lct` I get an oddly formated XML file.

[image]

What I expected from this was that each InnerText would be on the same line as the start and end tags of the XML element, but instead all but the last element's InnerText is located on a new line.

So my question is, why is that? Is there something else I could be doing with my XML elements to have their InnerText appear on the same line?

Comment: XML is a data format - not a display one. How IE choose to display an XML document (in the absence of a stylesheet) is entirely up to it, and apparently this is how it chooses to display XML elements with mixed content.

Comment: If you want to see what the true XML looks like, open it in Notepad or Notepad++ (or some similar text editor, even in Visual Studio).  As Damien_The_Unbeliever said... IE is displaying the XML the way it wants.  Not the way you always expect.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, XML isn't a display format, so it gets formatted however IE chooses to do so.

To get closer to what you were expecting, you might want to consider using an attribute rather than innertext:

```
XmlElement temp = (XmlElement)rootXmlElement.AppendChild(xDocument.CreateElement(lct));
var attr = xDocument.CreateAttribute("type");
attr.Value = lct;
temp.Attributes.Append(attr);
```

IE displays the attributes within the opening element, which may be good enough for your purposes.

---

From the XML perspective, what you're currently creating is called Mixed Content - you have an element that contains both text and other elements. From a hierarchical perspective, those text nodes and other elements occupy the same position within the hierarchy - so I'd assume that this is why IE is displaying them as "equals" - both nested under their parent element and at the same indentation level.